# After Flush Catalog Images cache from magento2 admin images not showing in frontend

Tags: magento2

In Magento admin System > Cache Management and then click on button Flush Catalog Images Cache.

Then Images not showing in frontend.

But If I apply below command then Images showing

```
php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

Can I need everytime apply this command? or Is any some server configuration missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you flush catalog images cache then This command is a must if you are using magento 2.1.x.

No worries any more about your server configuration

Comment: I am using magento2.3.2